# JMeter load is not increasing when we increase the threads count

Tags: jmeter

Load is not getting increased in AppD when we increase the threads count in JMeter. For example, if we are able to achieve 100k calls/min for 500 users with 20 ms avg response time. Load remains at 135 k with 25ms avg resp time when we give 1200 as threads in JMeter. Even we increase the load thrice, load is not going to the application. Didn't observe errors in JMeter as well. We are giving host entries in all the load generators. Is that could be a reason for controlling the load from JMeter? Request help to resolve this issue please

Answer (score 0):

As depicted in the following graph, the relationship between the load (Uvsers) and KPIs such as Throughput (TP) is **non-linear**. At certain point, increasing the load will not result on an increased Throughput that is proportional/linear (the *Heavy Load zone*).

[image: Relationship between the load and KPIs]

Comment: What's buckie zone? What is the graph origin?

Comment: It should read **Buckle **. The graph can be found [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/500812251/), towards the middle of the page

Comment: A longer explanation about this subject: https://blogs.oracle.com/timesten/server-scalability-curves-a-missing-law-of-computing

Answer (score 0):

If you increase the number of threads and the throughput is not increasing there could be 2 possible reasons for this:

1. The throughput is not increasing as response time is increasing which indicates your application [performance bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing), look at [Response Times vs Threads](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads/) and the point where the response time starts increasing will match the maximum number of users your application can support
2. JMeter is not capable of sending requests fast enough due to lack of resources or improper configuration, make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and if it doesn't help - consider allocating more load generator machines and switch to [Distributed Mode of JMeter tests execution](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)