# HTTPD response time is increasing after 90 TPS

Tags: apache, openshift, httpd.conf

I am doing load test to tune my apache to server maximum concurrent https request. Below is the details of my test.

**System**

1. I dockerized my httpd and deployed in openshift with pod configuration is 4CPU, 8GB RAM.
2. Running load from Jmeter with 200 thread, 600sec ramup time, loop is for infinite. duration is long run (Jmeter is running in same network with VM configuration 16CPU, 32GB RAM ).
3. I compiled by setting module with **worker** and deployed in openshift.

**Issue**

1. Httpd is not scaling more than **90TPS**, even after tried multiple mpm worker configuration (no difference with default and higher configuration)
   2.Issue which i'am facing after 90TPS, average time is  increasing and TPS is dropping.

Please let me know what could be the issue, if any information is required further suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer, but I do have questions.

1/ What does your Dockerfile look like?

2/ What does your OpenShift cluster look like?  How many nodes?  Separate control plane and workers?  What version?

2b/ Specifically, how is traffic entering the pod (if you are going in via a route, you'll want to look at your load balancer; if you want to exclude OpenShift from the equation then for the short term, expose a NodePort and have Jmeter hit that directly)

3/ Do I read correctly that your single pod was assigned 8G ram limit?  Did you mean the worker node has 8G ram?

4/ How did you deploy the app -- raw pod, deployment config?  Any cpu/memory limits set, or assumed?  Assuming a deployment, how many pods does it spawn?  What happens if you double it?  Doubled TPS or not - that'll help point to whether the problem is inside httpd or inside the ingress route.

5/ What's the nature of the test request?  Does it make use of any files stored on the network, or "local" files provisioned in a network PV.

And,

6/ What are you looking to achieve?  Maximum concurrent requests in *one* container, or maximum requests in the cluster?  If you've not already look to divide and conquer -- more pods on more nodes.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the questions, please find the answer. 1 -> Its is our internal file, where we have base image, we extend the base and install httpd. 2 -> Openshift version is v3.11.0+739ab57-285, we have enough app node running in the cluster, for load test i exposed the service vid nodeport.  3 -> ya all worker node have 16CPU and 32 GB nodes. 4-> deployment with docker-compose, i'm bench marking for one pod. 5 -> Files in PV 6-> I'm looking to achieve max concurrent request for per container.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have run into a bottleneck/limitation at the SUT. See the following  post for a detailed answer:

[JMeter load is not increasing when we increase the threads count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65171820/jmeter-load-is-not-increasing-when-we-increase-the-threads-count/65175482#65175482)